# How do I sort a PG table primarily by a timestamp column, but last_updated takes precedence?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to sort my table (containing drafts) by their timestamp, youngest first/topmost, but taking precedence to the "last_updated" timestamp column. That is, whatever record has been either created or updated the most recent is in the top/beginning of the returned records, and the oldest created or edited is in the bottom. It sounds very simple, but I have tried everything now and it just doesn't seem to behave correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY last_updated DESC, timestamp DESC;
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC, last_updated DESC;
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY last_updated ASC, timestamp ASC;
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp ASC, last_updated ASC;
```

Neither of these yield the right result. Note that last_updated can be null (it is until the draft has been edited at least once after being created).

What am I missing? Surely this is one of the simplest queries one could possibly make?

Comment: Your desired ordering is unclear to me. Please come up with a few sample rows in the desired order.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if these are bank drafts or drafts of novel, or American football player drafts.  Fortunately, it doesn't really matter to the answer.

```
ORDER by greatest(last_updated, timestamp) desc
```

"greatest" simply ignores NULL inputs, which seems to be desired.  Neither colmns is "taking precedence" over the other, unless the other column is NULL.  It is the values, not the columns they are from, where takes precedence over the other.